# Merge two exe files via python

Tags: python, windows, merge, build, exe

I want to merge two exe files through python and I've come to the conclusion that the easiest method of doing this would be to make an executable file that has both exe's in its resources and runs the resources of one exe, then the resources of the other (they do not have to execute simultaneously, rather just be packed into one file and take turns executing).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you wanting both executable's to run when you open the single application file? .exe files have headers and usually you can't run two applications from one. This is also almost exclusively used for malicious programs which is a big no no as you can encrypt the malicious program and have a seemingly "good" program un-encrypt and run the malicious one. There are multiple ways to do this but I am almost 100% sure you are not able to exclusively do this with python as you would need a 3rd program to run on top and unpack the other two before running (which would need to be compile-able)

Comment: I think you should explain *why* you would want to do this. If it is simply a matter of getting 2 programs to run in sequence, the normal way to do it would be to use a batch file/shell script.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (which isn't simple at all) would be to first write a program in a compile-able language like c or c++. This program would open itself and look for a delimiter of when the next program begins.

Example:

[exe header][code]{delimiter}[program2]

From there you can read that code and write it into a new exe file (if the second program is a exe) or multiple other ways. Then run the second program. Python could be used to pack the second program onto the first one but...

This is almost exclusively used for malicious programs as the "unpacking" program can be made to not be detected by anti-viruses and the malicious program can be encrypted. Due to this, this is as far as I will go and I won't be giving any examples.

If you have any specific questions about code your working on like errors or unexpected results I am sure many people would be up to helping you. Please let me know if you have any questions!